# 옛한글 on Safari not working

Tags: hangul, middle-korean, technology

I have a Mac and use Safari as my default browser. Across my Mac, despite having several fonts that support it, 옛한글 does not render how it is supposed to. For example ᄀᆞᇫ다 just appears as a string of text with 다 next to it. How can I fix this for Safari and or my entire computer so that 옛한글 renders correctly?

Comment: I think you'll have better luck asking about this on superuser stackexchange(https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is there a way to crosspost things? Or should I just repost it there?

Comment: you can just repost it there. There may not be many people who know what 옛한글 is, but  if you can manage to explain that what you want to display is ᄀᆞᇫ다 and it's not working, someone might be able to tell you how to fix it. You can leave this question here as well if you want, someone here might be able to answer it as well.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1696588/old-hangul-%ec%98%9b%ed%95%9c%ea%b8%80-on-safari-not-rendering

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the text engine on macOS doesn't fall back to additional CJK fonts that have better range of supported glyphs. You could probably fix Safari by a custom CSS injection, but I'd suggest you go with Firefox, which provides a relatively easy way to set custom fonts for specific languages.

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use . I tried Noto CJK and it worked.